# Sending Data to Azure Using Oracle EBS

Tags: oracle, azure, bpel, oracle-ebs, oracle-soa

I have a requirement where i need to send information to Azure. i tried web service but it throws me an error. Then someone suggested to use SOA Suite , i am unsure how to use it. Can somebody guide.

Regards,

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's totally unclear what you want to do. "send information to Azure" is not a question. Azure is a whole platform, not something in itself that you could store any data in. Do you mean Azure Blob Storage? Azure SQL, etc.?

Comment: So , we have a requirement that we need to send data from Oracle to another ERP and they have used AZURE as middleware , so we need to send data to the Azure and from there it will be sent to another ERP. I do not have much knowledge on Azure. I hope this can give some insights on what i want to achieve. we tried connecting Oracle EBS to AZURE by calling Webservice but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment...

The fact they're using Azure to host their web service is irrelevant. It still follows the ABC rules of Web Services - Address, Binding, Contract.

When you say calling their web service is "not working", how? What error message are you getting?

Comment: My first question will be can we call azure public cloud webservice directly from Oracle EBS Database?

Answer (score 0):

SOA suite would be the place to start if you're performing integration with another system - depending on the release of EBS you would want the [12.1 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/index.htm) or [12.2 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/nav/technology.htm) .  The technology section has an integration section which includes:

- Installing Oracle E-Business Suite Integrated SOA Gateway - MOS Note 1311068.1
- Oracle E-Business Suite Integrated SOA Gateway Developer's Guide
- Oracle E-Business Suite Integrated SOA Gateway Implementation Guide
- Oracle E-Business Suite Integrated SOA Gateway User's Guide

Comment: I did all the above , but i am facing issue calling the webservice.