# Invoking REST API using Oracle SOA Suite

Tags: web-services, soa, bpel, oracle-ebs, oracle-soa

Did anyone worked on calling REST webservice for sending the Json Payload information to Azure Public Cloud from Oracle SOA Suite. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this functionality as i am new to Oracle SOA Suite.

Comment: Seems like a similar (and broad) question to the one you asked before- you may want to should read the documentation referenced there and see if you have more specific questions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58307873/sending-data-to-azure-using-oracle-ebs/58345539

Comment: I read the documentations and tried calling REST webservice , but i was unsuccessful, dont know what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How did you call the REST API from oracle soa suite?Oracle SOA Suite supports REST Adapter to invoke REST API.Can you please post the error if you have used REST adapter in soa suite?

Comment: I did the same , but i need to assign authorization headers so i am unsure where i need to do that as i need to assign key and value as authorization header.

Comment: Azure REST API are secured with OAuth token..You need to get the OAuth bearer token from Azure and pass it in the REST API call as  Authorization <bearer token>..Hope you have registered a client application in Azure for OAuth configuration

Comment: I have a link of azure webservice and we need to generate SAS token on our own on every webservice call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the Rest Adapter and invoking it using the invoke component in the BPEL, you can modify the headers by double-clicking on the invoke component then selecting the headers tab. There you can select a header variable that you already filled with the authentication details needed.

Another option that is not recommended but will do the trick for you is to use the java embedded component in the BPEL and use it to write pure Java code to call the API.